# JDBC/Hibernate Fetch Size and memory issues

Tags: java, hibernate, memory, jdbc, out-of-memory

After investigating a bit at work I noticed that the application I'm working on is using the default fetch size (which is 10 for Oracle from what I know). The problem is that in the majority of cases the users fetch large amount of data (ranging from few thousand to even hundreds of thousands) and that the default 10 is really a huge bottleneck.

So the obvious conclusion here would be to make the fetch size larger. At first I was thinking about setting the default to 100 and bumping it to a 1000 for several queries. But then I read on the net that the default is so small to prevent memory issues (i.e. when the JVM heap cannot handle so much data), should I be worried about it?

I haven't seen anywhere further explanation to this. Does it mean that a bigger fetch sizes means more overhead while fetching the result set? Or do they just mean that with the default I can fetch 10 records and then GC them and fetch another 10 and so on (whereas lets say fetching a 10000 all at once would result in an OutOfMemory exception)? In such case I wouldn't really care as I need all the records in the memory anyway. In the former case (where bigger result set means bigger memory overhead) I guess I should load test it first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By setting the fetch size too, big you *are* risking `OutOfMemoryError`.

The fact that you need all these **records** anyway is probably not justifiable. More chances you need the **entities** reflected by the returned `ResultSet`s... Setting the fetch size to 10000 means you're heaping 10000 records represented by JDBC classes. Of course, you don't pass these around through your application. You first transform them into your favorite business-logic-entities and then hand them to your business-logic-executor. This way, The records form the first fetch bulk are available for GC as soon as JDBC fetches the next fetch bulk.

Typically, this transformation is done a little bunch at a time exactly because of the memory threat aforementioned.

One thing you're absolutely right, though: you **should** test for performance with **well-defined requirements** before tweaking.

Comment: Hm so basically when bumping the fetch size from 10 to lets say 100 I only get 90more jdbc objects on the heap and they will be GCed right after a call (so all the time I will have at most 100 jdbc objects at the heap)?

Comment: Yes, 100 jdbc objects that belong to the iterated `ResultSet`. Or, at least, that would be considered a reasonable implementation... It is not forced by the JDBC spec AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

> So the obvious conclusion here would be to make the fetch size larger.

Perhaps an equally obvious conclusion should be: "Let's see if we can cut down on the number of objects that users bring back."  When Google returns results, it does so in batches of 25 or 50 sorted by greatest likelihood to be considered useful by you.  If your users are bringing back thousands of objects, perhaps you need to think about how to cut down on that.  Can the database do more of the work?  Are there other operations that could be written to eliminate some of those objects?  Could the objects themselves be smarter?

Comment: Well that was my "second number one" but after consulting some of my coworkers who have way bigger "business" knowledge the conclusion was simple: we need to all the data to be in the memory. So unfortunately I do not see a way of cutting the numbers down.

Comment: Then you need more memory - no two ways about it.  And if you're running a 32 bit JVM, you'll run up against the 2GB JVM heap size limit.  There's nothing you can do about that, except go to 64 bits and allocating a much larger heap.

Comment: Yup, I know that :) My whole question was more like "I have XXXk objects in the memory anyway, will boosting the fetch size from 10 to 100/1000 will be a big deal in such case", but I guess I just need to request some decent load tests to see what happens.